# Meteor - Problems caused by Meteor.user() not defined at initial page load. How can I wait until Meteor.user() is available/defined?

Tags: meteor

In my Meteor app I have some collections I would like to subscribe to immediately upon login, and other collections I would like to subscribe to when the user visits or revisits the initial home page, but not otherwise.

The first set of collections should always be subscribed to throughout, but the second set should be turned off and on as the user leaves and returns to the initial screen.

I have the following code:

```js
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.subscribe('collection_one', Meteor.user().profile.setting_one);
    Meteor.subscribe('collection_two', Meteor.user().profile.setting_two);
});

Router.route('/', {
    name: 'home',
    path: '/',
    template: 'home',
    waitOn: function() {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe('collection_three', Meteor.user().profile.setting_three),
            Meteor.subscribe('collection_four', Meteor.user().profile.setting_four),
        ]
    }
});
```

My problem is that immediately upon startup and immediately upon going to the home page, Meteor.user() returns undefined.  I would like to wait until Meteor.user() is defined, and then take these actions.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor.startup() does not run code as a reactive computation, so even though Meteor.user() is a reactive data source it won't trigger a computation.

The [reactivity section of the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivity) has a list of functions that run code as reactive computations.

You can use Tracker (previously called 'Deps') to create a reactive computation, like this:

```
Tracker.autorun(function () {
  if (Meteor.user()) {
    Meteor.subscribe('collection_one', Meteor.user().profile.setting_one);
    Meteor.subscribe('collection_two', Meteor.user().profile.setting_two);
  }
});
```

But it looks like you're using Iron Router so you could also set a global waitOn() with Router.configure to solve it, like this:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'MasterLayout',
  loadingTemplate: 'Loading',
  notFoundTemplate: 'NotFound',
  templateNameConverter: 'upperCamelCase',
  routeControllerNameConverter: 'upperCamelCase',

  // This method will re-run when ever Meteor.user() changes.
  waitOn: function () {

    // Making sure setting_one and setting_two are available (which they won't be initially)
    var setting_one = Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().profile && Meteor.user().profile.setting_one;
    var setting_two = Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().profile && Meteor.user().profile.setting_one;

    // Subscribe to the published version of the server side collections
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('collection_one', setting_one),
      Meteor.subscribe('collection_two', setting_two)
    ];
  }
});
```

Comment: The `Tracker.autorun` solution is probably the more correct logic.  Wouldn't the `waitOn` solution not be reactive? (even though it will solve his initialization problem of `Meteor.user()` not being populated)

Comment: @colllin - The waitOn() of Iron Router is actually reactive so it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use `Tracker.autorun()`

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Tracker } from 'meteor/tracker';

let username = ''
Tracker.autorun( function(currentComputation) {
    if (Meteor.user()) {
        username = Meteor.user().username
        if (username) // do something with username
        return
    }
})
```

`currentComputation` is optional